# function won't run the second part of the code how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code

```js
function CheckForm_1() {
    var F1 = document.getElementById('srch');
    var Lgth = document.getElementById('srch');
    if (F1.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("Empty_Err");
        Empty_Err.style.display = 'inline';
        Empty_Err.stylebackgroundColor = 'linen';
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    if (Lgth.value.length > 17 || Lgth.value.length < 4) {
        document.getElementById("Length_Err");
        Length_Err.style.display = 'inline';
        backgroundColor = 'linen';
        alert("Search length must be be between 4 and 17");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I can't get it to check the field length Any ideas on this?
The code will run a check for an empty field just fine.

Comment: why do you do 2 assigns with `document.getElementById('srch');`? you dont need to repeat it for 2 variables

Comment: When you use `return`, you stop the function execution because you returned a value, so the function is terminated...that's why you'll never reach the second `if`, because in the first `if` you return or true or false...

Comment: You `return` from both `if` branches (F1.value empty or not) - what do you expect?

Comment: i am still kinda working on knowing javascript.

Comment: @bobronald remove the first `else`, where you are returning true. Also, fix the typo in `Empty_Err.stylebackgroundColor`

Comment: @bobronald Did you need to return a boolean value? Or do you want to function to stop at `return false`?

Comment: I am not sure. I really don't know javascript that well.

Answer (score 1):

Returning value will stop execution of a function.

As @Calvin Nunes commented

> When you use return, you stop the function execution because you
>   returned a value, so the function is terminated...that's why you'll
>   never reach the second if, because in the first if you return or true
>   or false

```js
function CheckForm_1() {
  var F1 = document.getElementById('srch');
  var errorMessage = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
  if (F1.value == "") {
    errorMessage.style.display = 'inline';
    errorMessage.style.backgroundColor = 'linen';
    errorMessage.innerHTML= "Search field is empty";
  } else if (F1.value.length > 17 || F1.value.length < 4) {
    errorMessage.style.display = 'inline';
    errorMessage.style.backgroundColor = 'linen';
    errorMessage.innerHTML = 'Search length must be be between 4 and 17';
  } else {
    errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='srch' type="text" />
<div id="errorMessage" style="display:none">Search field is empty</div><br>
<button type="button" onclick="CheckForm_1()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Hey @Pete, added some explanation. Thanks for reminding.